# How to disable the Dual MFA from the users account?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have my user who is able to login to Systems (Okta, Emails) where it is using MFA (Google Authentication) but when the same user is trying to login to other Application (Azure DevOps with same userID and password it is asking for the Microsoft Authentication. Users phone does not support Microsoft Authentication so we cannot use it.

1. My Question is why the user need to two different MFA how can we switch to only one MFA?
2. Is there a way we change to single MFA which is Google Authenticator only.

I did reset the Azure AD account and recreated the users Azure DevOps account and still no luck.

Please Assist

Thanks & Regards
Abhay

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about what's on topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [sf], though please check their documentation to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statement on "[**Microsoft Entra multifactor authentication**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/howto-mfa-getstarted#choose-authentication-methods-for-mfa)", the following are supported MFA methods when logging in Microsoft Azure applications:

- **Windows Hello for Business**
- **Microsoft Authenticator app**
- **FIDO2 security key (preview)**
- **OATH hardware tokens (preview)**
- **OATH software tokens**
- **SMS verification**
- **Voice call verification**

The **Google Authentication** method is not available here.